# What does xor [si], si does in asm x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, xor

I have the cipher code in asm of a "historical" malware (cascade 1701).
However, I can't understand what is the point of the instruction xor [si], si. Code below :

```
             lea si, Start
             mov sp, 0682
Decrypt :    xor [si], si
             xor [si], sp
             inc si
             dec sp
             jnz Decrypt
Start :      ...
```

For me, it seems like [si] will be assigned to a kind of random value because there is no obvious link between si dans [si] (at least nothing predictible).
Thanks for help !

All the researches I did end up by explaining me the point of xor XX, XX which I understand... But xor [XX], XX ?!

Comment: It's using the XOR of a counter (in SP which is insane) and the address of the byte as decryption "keys".  With overlapping 2-byte XORs but advancing the pointer by 1 byte.  It's not any kind of standard thing like xor-zeroing, it's just a choice that saves registers, using the address instead of a separate counter.

Answer (score 4):

In Intel assembly, (and also in variants, such as the "ideal" mode introduced by Borland, which is what your code snippet probably uses,) the order of the operands is "target <- source". (The same as the order in which operands appear in assignment statements of high-level languages.)

`XOR [SI], SI` XORs the contents of the address pointed by `si` with the value of `si` and stores the result back in that address. It is perfectly legitimate, albeit very weird assembly.

XORing is a very well known naive encryption strategy. In its most simple form, it consists of XORing each value in an array with a constant, so it would be something like `XOR [si], 01ah`.

The problem with this simple encryption form is that it produces predictable patterns, because 'a' will always translate to a certain value, 'b' to some other, but again always same value, etc.

Another, slightly more advanced (but by modern encryption standards equally naive) approach is to use a different value to XOR with for each index along the encrypted array. That's what `XOR [SI], SI` accomplishes, since `SI` will have a different value in each iteration.

What is weird about this particular implementation of encryption-by-xor is that, (among other things,) it assumes that the array of characters to encrypt resides at a fixed memory address, and that it will be the exact same address when the algorithm is reapplied in order to decrypt.

(Note that the terms encrypt/decrypt are used interchangeably here, since the same algorithm is used both for encryption and decryption: decryption simply consists of reapplying the algorithm.)

So, what this probably means is that the author of this code has taken pains to ensure that the buffer will always be at an expected memory address, in other words the value of `Start:` will be the same both when encrypting and decrypting.

This is extremely hacky, but assembly language programmers are generally known for doing extremely hacky stuff like that.

Malware programmers doubly so.

Note that the `Start:` label may be misleading. This code was probably disassembled. The author used the `LEA` instruction as a means of loading the address of the buffer into `SI`, and the disassembler is in the habit of creating a label for the target of any `LEA` instruction, without necessarily knowing how the segment registers are arranged. Therefore, if the `Start:` label is in fact in code, as the snippet indicates, then what is probably happening is that the disassembler for some reason assumed that the DS register contains the same value as the CS register, and therefore SI is being loaded with the address of some instruction, while what is probably happening instead is that SI is being set to point to some buffer in the data segment, which is different, at that moment, from the code segment. If this hypothesis is true, then the code is actually less hacky than it seems to be.

---

<sup>For a short story (literature, non-fiction) describing an incident of hacking from my university years back in the early nineties, where I cracked the password that Norton Utilities was protected with, see https://blog.michael.gr/2017/09/a-hackers-tale.html The Norton Utilities was in fact using the simplest form of this naive xoring algorithm, and my approach to cracking their password would have worked even if the slightly more advanced form had been used.</sup>

Comment: `xor byte [si], 1Ah` is encodeable, so is `xor word [si], 1Ah`.  Because `[si]` is a valid addressing mode, and `xor r/m, imm8` is a valid instruction (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xor), so is `imm16`.  Of course any sane assembler would require you to specify an operand-size, since neither memory nor immediate imply one.

Comment: There's nothing hacky about loading the address of a buffer into a register.  That's just what `mov sp, offset buffer` assembles to.

Comment: @fuz I did not say that there is anything hacky in loading the address of a buffer into a register. And I did not write anything about `sp`. I wrote about `si`, and what I identified as hacky, (and is in fact very-very hacky,) is to assume that the buffer is at a particular memory location and therefore the value loaded into the register is a very specific value, where a different value will cause the encryption/decryption to fail.

Comment: Remember that 16-bit DOS used a segmented memory model, so segment bases could be runtime-variable while offsets were link-time constants.  Remember, this is malware, intentionally obfuscated.  So yes, hacky in that sense, but not in the "bad design" sense.  To generate the right data, your build process might even involve finding out where the linker put a string (or whatever binary data) and "encrypting" it using the offset, instead of hard-coding the encrypted data in the source.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have already amended my answer to account for the possibility of different segments.

Comment: I was commenting about the *it assumes that the array of characters to encrypt resides at a fixed memory address* part - only the offset part needs to stay fixed for this to still work when the code is loaded at different places in linear address space.  And it *will* stay constant because there normally aren't runtime-fixups for offsets, just using different segment bases.  Not about the CS: vs. DS: stuff about where the disassembler put the label vs. what might actually be getting decrypted.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, but look: the OP shows `lea si, Start` and `Start:` appears to be right after the end of the loop. I can understand it if some instructions have been omitted, but if a whole new segment declaration was there, I would have expected it to be included in the snippet. So, the disassembly output seems to indicate that the address of the buffer depends on the length of the code, which would make it extremely difficult to guarantee consistency.

Comment: Therefore, in order to assume a different segment, we have to begin by assuming that either the snippet is misleading, or the disassembly is misleading.

Comment: It's malware; presumably they assembled it and then post-processed the binary to apply that encryption starting at that offset, perhaps with a manually configured offset that they'd update in their build script if it ever needed to change (because the length of the preceding code changed).  I'd guess this is just a very small stub near the start of a .com executable.  The initial SP value (length) might also be automatically edited into the binary by the encryption process, replacing the immediate for the `mov` also at a known offset.

Comment: It reminds me of a trick for linked lists, which involved XORing the pointers together to save memory, but I don't remember exactly how it worked or where I read about it sadly.